# Gmail mails of others coming to me

Tags: gmail

My email ID on Gmail is `Sandeep.bhargava@gmail.com`. I am getting emails sent to:

```
sandeepbhargava@gmail.com
sandeep_bhargava@gmail.com
```

I think this is an error in Gmail logic. As a result, I am getting other people’s emails. How can I report this to Google?

Answer (score 1):

dots and upper cases are omitted so if your email is **`sandeep.bhargava@gmail.com`** you can send a message to these emails and it will always ends in your inbox:

```
Sandeep.bhargava@gmail.com
SANDEEP.BHARGAVA@gmail.com
SaNdEeP.BhArGaVa@gmail.com
sandeepbhargava@gmail.com
s.a.n.d.e.e.p.b.h.a.r.g.a.v.a@gmail.com
san.DEEP.bhar.Gava@gmail.com
sandeep.bhargava+anytext@gmail.com
sandeepbhargava+theworldismine@gmail.com
s.a.nd.eep.bha.rga.va+IamTheBest@gmail.com
sandeepbhargava+SEND.ME.SPAM@gmail.com
```

you can report issues on Google forum - **[https://productforums.google.com/forum/](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail)**

good thing is that Google's Gmail Team actually reads this forum. also you can send direct feedback from your Gmail account and address your issues non-publicly:

- enter your gmail - **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox**
- on the top right press the **Gear button** (Settings)
- select **Send Feedback**

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about these emails

```
Sandeep.bhargava@gmail.com.
sandeepbhargava@gmail.com
sandeep_bhargavaemphasized text@gmail.com.
```

The explanation is that you are mistaken. Your email username is lowercase, and no special characters and certainly no cursive or emphasized text.

gmail ignores upper case and dots `.`, and everything that comes after `+`. That is why everything sendt to all variations, including:

```
Sandeep.bh..argava@gmail.com.
San.Deep.bharGava@gmail.com.
sandeep.bhargava+onfire@gmail.com.
```

end in the one and only true inbox - belonging the the one and same user - `sandeepbhargava`.

You should not report this, as it is not an error.

I have no idea what the deal with `sandeep_bhargavaemphasized text@gmail.com.` is - maybe an error in your post!?